# Find a record containing all or a part of a list of id of other table in a many-to-many relation on MySql/Jpa?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, many-to-many

In my web application, I have 3 tables:

- TAB A: Recipes (id, name)
- TAB B: Recipes_Ingredients(id, fk_recipe,fk_ingredient, quantity) *Bridge table*
- TAB C: Ingredients (id, name)

I need to find all the recipes(TAB A) that containing a provided list of ingredients (TAB C).

Es:

I provide a list of ingredients id like 111 (spaghetti), 222(pepper), 333(oil) and I need to find all the recipes that containing these ingredients. The query should return me all those recipes that contain at most these ingredients.

So if I run a search like this:

```
...
WHERE TAB_B.fk_ingredients IN (111,222,333)  // IT DOESN'T WORKS AS I WISH
...
```

It must return a list of recipe that a list of recipes they contain MAX thath ingredients (111,222,333) and MINIMUM one of the ingredients I passed it.

Result Example:

| id | name | list_fk_ingredients (es.) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Spaghetti with pepper | 111,222 |
| 2 | Spaghetti with oil | 111,333 |
| 3 | Pepper with nothing | 222 |
| 4 | Spaghetti with everything | 111,222,333 |

I would also need a way to report the query back to JPA.

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: Dont you want to be looking at `fk_ingredients` to locate a recipt with an ingredient. So `WHERE fk_ingredients IN (111,222,333)`

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
@Akina , can you be a little more explicit? Maybe writing a simple query with 'TAB A', 'TAB B' ecc... Thnaks again

Comment: Post textual code-formatted: CREATE TABLE for all tables, INSERT INTO with the data which must result in shown output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ri.recipes_id
FROM recipes_ingredients ri
GROUP BY ri.recipes_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ri.ingredients_id NOT IN (111,222,333) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) =0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a subquery where you join the tables then group them by Recipes

```
SELECT R.name, count(R.id) AS sum
FROM Recipes as R
join Recipes_Ingredients as RI on R.id=RI.fk_recipe
group by R.id
```

It will output you a list of all the recipes with a count of how many ingredients each have. I named the count of ingredients as sum in here.

You don't need to join the ingredients table.

Next, you just select the records which have 3 or less and 1 or more from this query using a WHERE statement.

```
SELECT R.name, sum
FROM (SELECT R.name, count(R.id) AS sum
FROM Recipes as R
join Recipes_Ingredients as RI on R.id=RI.fk_recipe
group by R.id) as T
WHERE sum <= 3
AND sum >=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it is very useful that in this way I can find exactly the number of ingredients in a recipe, however it is not exactly the solution I was looking for.

I need to find all those recipes that contain a list of ingredients_id (which will always be dynamic) containing NO OTHERS ids outside the list I provided.
Example: i provide oil (id=111) bread=(id=222) result recipes: OK oil+bread, OK bread, OK oil, NO oil+ salt NO bread + oil + salt